# Модифицировать стандартный quicksort добавив выбор разделяющего элемента с помощью медианы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Требуется модифицировать стандартный quicksort добавив выбор разделяющего элемента с помощью медианы. Не понимаю как это делать. Кто-нибудь может привести готовый код на C++?

Answer (score 1):

Тут все просто - когда вы выбираете опорный элемент, нужно брать его не, как обычно, первым, а взять, скажем, три элемента (обычно берут первый, последний и средний по местоположению), сравнить, и в качестве опорного выбрать средний из них (не по местоположению, конечно, а по значению).

Если бы вы привели свой код быстрой сортировки, то показать на нем, как его модифицировать, было бы проще. Просить готовый код здесь не комильфо :)